# How to remove pod spec file from CocoaPods / Specs

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I created a public pod , now I wanted to delete the pod spec because of some security concerns

Answer (score 0):

`pod trunk delete PODNAME VERSION`

Care must be taken while doing this. If someone is using your spec file, you can damage the person's project after this process.

Comment: Actually my Podspec file contains sensitive information , so I wanted to remove my Podspec file from CocoaPods/spec repository . please help me out in achieving it

Comment: To delete these specs entirely you'll need to submit a pull request to the [specs repo](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs) removing the affected files.